# Debugging Apache/Django/WSGI Bad Request (400) Error

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

My simple Django app worked fine in debug mode (`manage.py runserver`), and works under WSGI+Apache on my dev box, but when I pushed to EC2 I began receiving intermittent (10-80% of the time) errors of `Bad Request (400)` for any URLs I try to view (whether in my app or in the Django admin.

Where can I find debug information about this? Nothing appears in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, even with `LogLevel=info`. I have checked versions, logged the Request environment (cf. [ModWSGI Debugging Tips](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Displaying_Request_Environment)) and see no major differences.

The one remaining thought I had is, I'm using the mod_wsgi from Ubuntu 12.04 (libapache2-mod-wsgi 3.3-4build1) which was built against Python 2.7.1; I have Python 2.7.3. And Django is 1.6, which is newer than the Ubuntu Precise version. I hesitate to start building packages from source since it's so hard to clean up and these seem like minor version changes...

**Thank you for your help.**

*(For reference, here are the Apache config and WSGI apps)*

#### Apache config (000-default)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    WSGIScriptAlias /rz /usr/local/share/rz/rz.wsgi
    ...
```

#### rz.WSGI app

```
import os
import sys
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
import pprint

path = '/usr/local/share/rz'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'rz.settings'

class LoggingMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, application):
        self.__application = application

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        errors = environ['wsgi.errors']
        pprint.pprint(('REQUEST', environ), stream=errors)

        def _start_response(status, headers, *args):
            pprint.pprint(('RESPONSE', status, headers), stream=errors)
            return start_response(status, headers, *args)

        return self.__application(environ, _start_response)

application = LoggingMiddleware(django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())
```

Comment: set DEBUG = FALSE in django setting file. and try to restart apache server.

Comment: Why does DEBUG=FALSE make it more reliable? I have tried restarting and am not seeing any improvement.

Comment: Is [ALLOW_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS) set correctly? Django will reply with bad request, only in prod mode, if this is set incorrectly. If it's working correctly part of the time - perhaps clients are connecting via different hostnames, some of these hostnames may be missing from ALLOW_HOSTS.

Comment: Yes, you got it! Thank you, it was because production mode requires that setting. Wonder why it was intermittent, though...

Comment: I did a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` on a working virtual server, and afterward, got the 400 BAD REQUEST.  It led me to this post, and the solution was to add ALLOWED_HOSTS.  I assume this is because the upgrade changed to Django 1.5 or above.  Note [the **"Important"** comment here](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/feb/19/security/#s-issue-host-header-poisoning): *"by default Django 1.3.6 and 1.4.4 set ALLOWED_HOSTS to allow all hosts. This means that to actually fix the security vulnerability you should define this setting yourself immediately after upgrading."*

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Add the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting to your settings.py like so...

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '.example.com', # Allow domain and subdomains
    '.example.com.', # Also allow FQDN and subdomains
]
```

I had this same problem and found the answer [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

update: django 1.6 docs are no longer online, I updated the link to go to the django 1.7 docs for `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting.

Comment: Strange thing. This solution works only for localhost for me. When I'm trying to add `my_site.com` to ALLOWED_HOSTS (`127.0.0.1 my_site.com` in /etc/hosts) Bad Request (400) appears again. What's wrong?

Comment: @Anton What is your `DEBUG` set to? When you access your website via 'my_site.com' is there a setting that is changing the value of `DEBUG`? Could their be a typo in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting? I need more info :) My guess is you have a typo in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting and it's ignored when trying to access your website via '127.0.0.1' because that is setting DEBUG to False. When you are trying to access the site via 'my_site.com' your DEBUG is getting set to True and using `ALLOWED_HOSTS` which has a type. Do you have '.my_site.com' or 'mysite.com'?

Comment: DEBUG set to False.
I created a new clean project for testing so nothing can change the value of DEBUG (at least I hope so). I tried a lot of variants of ALLOWED_HOSTS: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'my_site.com', 'ubuntu-virtualbox']`. localhost and ubuntu-virtualbox -> works, my_site.com -> Bad Request, Then I tried to give access for all hosts: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` with the same result. And even when I changed DEBUG to True, only localhost and ubuntu-virtualbox were available. my_site.com is still returning Bad Request 
May it be because of virtualenv or some system settings?

Comment: here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357744/django-and-bad-request-400 .I can give more info there. It's too difficult to post code in comments.

Comment: Not having the site listed in ALLOWED_HOSTS was also my issue.  I did need to restart Apache after changing it, though.  Without restarting Apache, it continued to display the occasional http 400 bad request.

Comment: Docs link is broken

Comment: @Agey Oh yeah, it appears that django 1.6 documentation is no longer available. I'll fix the link for django 1.7.

Answer (score 9):

If you've definitely set `ALOWED_HOSTS` - make sure your hostname doesn't contain underscores. It's technically illegal.

I had to print out various functions and it boiled down to this regex failing to detect a domain in `django.http`

```
host_validation_re = re.compile(r"^([a-z0-9.-]+|\[[a-f0-9]*:[a-f0-9:]+\])(:\d+)?$")
```

And indeed, my domain had an underscore in it.

Comment: Bingo - after 45 minutes of hunting this down, your answer stuck out and sure enough, I had an underscore in the production domain (hosts file) but not in dev domain.  Very hard to debug this with DEBUG=False.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not a solution**, but for *debugging purposes* you might set the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting in your settings.py like this

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

It should definitely work. If not, at least you will know the problem isn't Django denying access to the given url.

Comment: Doing this you disable the security this variables intends to set.

Comment: @Mibou even with this setting, i've got bad request, when redirecting from one server to another..

Comment: This is good for DEBUG reasons, to determine if the problem is with ALOWED_HOSTS.