# Django and Bad Request (400)

Tags: django, bad-request

I created new django project;
added to my settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS= [
    'localhost',
    'my_site.com'
]
```

created app `test_view`;
added `hello_world` to `test_view.views`

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

def hello_world(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World!!!')
```

added test route to urls.py `url(r'test/', 'test_view.views.hello_world')`;
fixed /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1    localhost my_site.com
```

Now when i'm trying to access `http://my_site.com:8000/test/` django returns Bad Request (400). But when url is `http://localhost:8000/test/` I can see my Hello World page. What can be wrong?

**UPD:**
The same result with `DEBUG = True`

**UPD2:**

One more working hostname is `ubuntu-virtualbox` (computer's name).
But even when I changed computer's name to `my_site`, ubuntu-virtualbox was still available and my_site returned `Bad Request (400)`

May it be because of some system settings? (it's clean ubuntu in virtualbox).
Or maybe problem in virtualenv? Is there a way to trace the error?

Comment: `r'^test/$'` should be the correct regex I think.

Comment: maybe you can try to clean your arp cache table.

Comment: Also, your etc/hosts should only include `127.0.0.1 my_site.com`.

Comment: beginning with `.` will match my_site.com or www.my_site.com

Comment: Still no result. I'll try to add a new virtualenv and clean project.

Comment: No result even with new virtualenv.

Comment: did you try to clean your arp-cache table, you have to open cmd such as administrator and write netsh interface ip delete arpcache

Comment: Yes, I tried. Still Bad Request (400).

Comment: It looks like django can see if request isn't passed through dns server. Installation and configuration of bind9 instead of changes in /etc/hosts solved this problem.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a bad Cookie. Try deleting them.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like django can see if request isn't passed through dns server. Installation and configuration of bind9 instead of changes in /etc/hosts solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need another line in your hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
127.0.0.1     my_site.com
```

Then in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`...

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost',
    '.my_site.com', # not 'my_site.com'
]
```

ALSO, and this is probably important seeing as you are running your site from a virtual machine, when you run the site with python manage.py runserver, run it like this...

`python manage.py runserver virtual.server.ip.address:8000`

Obviously replace 'virtual.server.ip.address' with that virtual machines actual ip address.

Comment: It says `Error: That IP address can't be assigned to` error

Comment: @SarasArya try to run the development server like this `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` That will basically have it run on whatever your current ip address is. You should still be able to access the site from `localhost:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8000`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I print `*DEBUG = None*` and my django works.