# Django runserver - Can you output the connecting IP to the console?

Tags: django, debugging, logging, settings, django-runserver

I am trying to capture the IP address of incoming connections to the console using the development webserver that comes with django (`manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`).  Right now, I get the following output on requests:

```
[24/Feb/2022 13:03:38] "GET /admin/aqww/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
```

Is there a way to get an incoming client IP address in there?  For example, make it look something like the following?

```
[24/Feb/2022 13:03:38 192.168.1.34] "GET /admin/aqww/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
```

Comment: You can track ip of client with signals, `request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")`

Comment: Thanks, is there an easy way to force all requests to this code?  Even in bad requests?

Answer (score 0):

In bad request, you can't get ip as far as i know, since it client error.

But you can get ip with `request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")`.

For bad requests you can consider several posts of stack overflow such as:

[1 post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875789/django-gives-bad-request-400-when-debug-false)

[2 post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357744/django-and-bad-request-400)