# Django doesn't show text body of HttpResponses with 4xx status code

Tags: python, django, nginx, httpresponse, http-status-code-400

The following Django HttpResponse doesn't show any text in the browser and I don't know why:

```
HttpResponse(u'Bad Request - Text does not show.', status=400, content_type='text/plain')
```

It works perfectly on my localhost, but the text message is not found anywhere when running the same code under NGINX in production.

Here's a production example URL:
http://pixabay.com/get/abc.svg

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the network details in the console, I see two requests to the svg. One is a 307 (internal redirect), the other is the 400 (to 78.47.54.106:443, for my instance) you mentioned. I'd suggest to look into the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting, as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20618753/2672370) recommends.

Comment: Nginx is probably cutting this for some of the status_codes - try changing 400 to something acceptable (200, 201, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, or 307) and see if this works.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I found the solution. It works when I remove the "u" in front of the string. Apparently, our NGINX has issues when it comes to unicode plain text bodies.